# Getting same value from javascript function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using following code to get different different colors using d3.scale.category10(). Here is my code:

```
function getDrawColor(i)
{
    var colors = d3.scale.category10();
//    for(var j=0;j<5;j++)
//    {
//        alert(colors(j));
//    }
          return colors(i);
}
```

When i try to print colors using the commented for loop, I am getting different different colors. But when i am calling this method with different valued of i, I am always getting the same color(i.e. color(0)),regardless of the value of i. I printed value of i,there is no problem but, I am always getting first color.

Answer (score 1):

Declare that colors in global, and use it inside of the get function like below

```
var colors = d3.scale.category10();
function getDrawColor(i)
{
  return colors(i);
}
```

Hope this will work for you...

Answer (score -1):

Check out this link,it  may perhaps help you: http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2011/08/11/d3-scales-and-color/

This section may help you :

Color palettes

Unlike in protovis, which had them under pv.Colors – i.e. pv.Colors.category10(), in d3, built-in color palettes can be accessed through scales. Well, even in protovis they had been ordinal scales all along, only not called this way.
There are 4 built-in color palette in protovis: d3.scale.category10(), d3.scale.category20(), d3.scale.category20b(), and d3.scale.category20c().

A palette like d3.scale.category10() works exactly like an ordinal scale.

```
var p=d3.scale.category10();
var r=p.range(); // ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", 
                  // "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf"]
var s=d3.scale.ordinal().range(r); 
p.domain(); // [] - empty
s.domain(); // [] - empty, see above
p(0); // "#1f77b4"
p(1); // "#ff7f0e"
p(2); // "#2ca02c"
p.domain(); // [0,1,2];
s(0); // "#1f77b4"
s(1); // "#ff7f0e"
s(2); // "#2ca02c"
s.domain(); // [0,1,2];
```

It’s noteworthy that in d3, color palette return strings, not pv.Color objects like in protovis.
Also:

```
d3.scale.category10(1); // this doesn't work
d3.scale.category10()(1); // this is the way.
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Added section that may be useful.